# React Native : executing function multiple times when pressing a button

Tags: react-native

What I want to do is executing function multiple times when pressing the button.

```js
<Button onPress={()=>{console.log('execute')}}/>
```

If I use onPress, the function is executed only once, even if I does not press out.

But I hope `console.log` is executed multiple times in sequence (or every seconds) until press out.

Comment: The issue might be caused due to other code in your application, can you share the code of the screen or you also can try to put different log messages to crack the problem if there are several console logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I track how many times someone pressed with **hooks**:

```
const [lastPressed, setLastPressed] = useState(0);
const [pressedAmount, setPressedAmount] = useState(0);

const handlePress = useCallback(() => {
  const time = new Date().getTime();
  const delta = time - lastPressed;
  setLastPressed(time);
  if (lastPressed) {
    if (delta < DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY) {
      setPressedAmount(pressedAmount + 1);
    } else {
      setPressedAmount(0);
    }
  }
}, [lastPressed]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TouchableOpacity. In this example addOne function will execute every second.

```
  export default class App extends Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      number: 0,
    };
    this.timer = null;
    this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
  }

  addOne() {
    this.setState({number: this.state.number+1});
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.addOne, 1000);
  }

  stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPressIn={this.addOne} onPressOut={this.stopTimer}>
        <Text>Press me</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.number}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, on your reference, I used setInterval and clearInterver in onPressIn and onPressOut.